# how to invert pandas data into text data

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I want to make a simple spell corrector system and I have a datafarme like this:

```
incorrect_word, correct_word   
scoohl,school  
watn,want  
frienf,friend
```

"I watn to go scoohl"
I want to correct this sentence by replacing the incorrect sample in "incorrect_word" column with the correct sample in the "correct_word" column (if it exists)
how can i do this?
the sample code i wrote and does not work.

---

```
text = " شما رفتین مدرسه شون گفتین دستاشون رو بشورن"
# if "دستاشون رو" in text:
#     print("yes")
from hazm import *
import pandas as pd
from src.config.config import *

# letters = word_tokenize(text)
# for text in word_tokenize(text):
#     print(text)
df = pd.read_excel(FILL_DATA).astype(str)
text = str(text)
for idx, item in enumerate(df['informal']):
    if item in text:

        text = text.replace(item, df['formal1'].iloc[idx])
        # item = item.replace(df['informal'].iloc[idx], df['formal1'].iloc[idx])
print(text)
```

---

Comment: The data frame you are showing seems to have different columns with the data frame you are using. Could you give more details about the excel you are using?

Comment: yes, I give a simple data frame as an example above of the code, your right... @charalamm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['scoohl','school'], ['watn','want'], ['frienf','friend']], columns=['incorrect_word', 'correct_word'])
df.index = df['incorrect_word']
df.drop(columns=['incorrect_word'], inplace=True)

text_to_correct = "I watn to go scoohl"

words = text_to_correct.split(' ')

for c, w in enumerate(words):
    if w in df.index:
        words[c] = df.at[w,'correct_word']

words = ' '.join(words)
words
```

result :

```
'I want to go school'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is very basic python you can do it in this way

```
df['incorrect']=[x for x in df['Correct'] if len(x)>2]
```

You should search about lambda, list comprenhension, apply and map

Thank you.

Comment: hi there, unfortunately, your answer was compeletly wrong to "my question", thank you @jaime

Comment: Im sorry for that